# React native web-view vs Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, react-native

I have an app build using cordova. However, making it look properly on android is being a bit though. I read reac-native documentation and I thought about combining the current state of the app, embedding it on a web view and building the rest of the app using react-native.

The reason behind this is that I feel more comfortable building the android specific ui of the app (like sidebars, and menus) using react-native than cordova, and I want to know if this approach makes sense. Is react native web view as powerful as cordova? Does this make any sense?

Thanks and regards

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Do you have any update on this? It's almost 3 years later now. Wondering if you tried this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite React Native owns a [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) component I believe that this component is not appropriate for your approach.

From the docs:

> **WebView** renders web content in a native view. You can use this
>   component to navigate back and forth in the web view's history and
>   configure various properties for the web content.

The purpose of React Native WebView is simply "renders web content".

I believe that you can not simply put your current Cordova code inside a React Native Web View and "it works". If your current Cordova app is more than simple HTML pages and use some Cordova Plugin, for example, you will have problems at this point.

Added to this the fact that strange architecture will probably increase the maintenance cost.

And about React Native to be as powerful as Cordova: I would say that React Native is more promising and very powerful, but actually Cordova has a ecosystem more mature and consistent. Maybe you should take a look at [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/).

Answer (score 0):

> Is react native web view as powerful as Cordova?
>
> **Answer: It's more powerful than Cordova**

Unlike Cordova/PhoneGap your code runs in a JS runtime on the OS, but the UI is rendered as native components. This makes it very different than Cordova/PhoneGap.
You can use the standard platform components such as UITabBar on iOS and Drawer on Android. This gives your app a consistent look and feel with the rest of the platform ecosystem, and keeps the quality bar high. These components are easily incorporated into your app using their React component counterparts, such as TabBarIOS and DrawerLayoutAndroid.

As for Cordova, you're bound to the limitations of the WebView.And since JavaScript is single threaded, you will at one point run into issues if there are too many things going on in your application code. Such as sluggish animations etc...

Comment: It seems you didn't understand the question. He is comparing react native *webview* to cordova. Not React Native to Cordova.